# Python URWID color palette

Tags: python, urwid

I need help understanding how the coloring works for urwid

```
color_palette = [
    ('banner', '', '', '', '#fff', 'g35'),
    ('streak', 'white', '', '', 'g0', 'g35'),
    ('inside', '', '', '', 'g0', 'g35'),
    ('outside', '', '', '', 'g0', 'g35'),
    ('bg', '', '', '', 'g35', '#fff'),]
```

From the documentation:
http://urwid.org/manual/displayattributes.html#id6

Colors i would like to use:

```
 - #195c60
 - #193638
 - #232323
```

---

USAGE: http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html#high-color-modes

```
import urwid

def exit_on_q(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

palette = [
    ('banner', '', '', '', '#ffa', '#60d'),
    ('streak', '', '', '', 'g50', '#60a'),
    ('inside', '', '', '', 'g38', '#808'),
    ('outside', '', '', '', 'g27', '#a06'),
    ('bg', '', '', '', 'g7', '#d06'),]

placeholder = urwid.SolidFill()
loop = urwid.MainLoop(placeholder, palette, unhandled_input=exit_on_q)
loop.screen.set_terminal_properties(colors=256)
loop.widget = urwid.AttrMap(placeholder, 'bg')
loop.widget.original_widget = urwid.Filler(urwid.Pile([]))

div = urwid.Divider()
outside = urwid.AttrMap(div, 'outside')
inside = urwid.AttrMap(div, 'inside')
txt = urwid.Text(('banner', u" Hello World "), align='center')
streak = urwid.AttrMap(txt, 'streak')
pile = loop.widget.base_widget # .base_widget skips the decorations
for item in [outside, inside, streak, inside, outside]:
    pile.contents.append((item, pile.options()))

loop.run()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @zondo How do i use the colors i want?

Comment: @What's wrong with what you have?  We can't tell you *why* your code doesn't work if we don't know *what* doesn't work.

Comment: @zondo the code works fine. Its the implementation of the color pallet. "I need help understanding how the coloring works for urwid"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the urwid high color example with your custom colors.

In the example from the tutorial, the following line tells terminal to use the 8 bit terminal color mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color):

```
loop.screen.set_terminal_properties(colors=256)
```

To use your custom color, you need to convert your (presumably RGB) color to the closest possible corresponding 8 bit terminal color. Note that you won't necessarily be able to get an exact match: there are *way* more RGB hex color codes than 8 bit terminal color codes.

I used this tool to do find an approximate match for your colors: https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/719710

```
$ colortrans 195c60
RGB 195c60 -> xterm color approx 23 (005f5f)
$ colortrans 193638
RGB 193638 -> xterm color approx 23 (005f5f)
$ colortrans 232323
RGB 232323 -> xterm color approx 16 (000000)
```

With a modern urwid, you can then do:

```
palette = [
    ('color1', '', '', '', 'h23', 'h23'),
    ('color2', '', '', '', 'h16', 'h16'),]
```